# How to access html value of property that triggers an event in Meteor?

Tags: events, meteor, scope

If I have a list of items in my template, like this:

```js
<template name="myTemplate">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

And my event handler looks something like this:

```js
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click li': function(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget//.? .html, .value?
  }
});
```

How would I access the value of the li item that was clicked? i.e. I want to access 'One' or 'Two', etc. I tried .html and .value, which would have been the jquery-esque way to do it. My understanding is using 'currentTarget' is correct, since 'target' should match all li's, but I don't know how to hone in on the html value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.innerHTML is the answer.

```
console.log(event.currentTarget.innerHTML); // Outputs li HTML content
```

Answer (score 1):

As anonymous say. use the native attribute innerHTML to get the content of a DOM element.
otherwise Meteor come with JQuery so you can use it like this

`console.log($(event.currentTarget).html());`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click li': function(event) {
   $(event.target).html()
//console.log(event.currentTarget//.? .html, .value?
  }
});
```